# Unmount/detach/deactivate PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I manage a server that serves several web applications that use PostgreSQL as a data store.  Each web application has a separate role and database, and each database is stored exclusively on a dedicated tablespace on a different logical file system.

What I would like to be able to do is unmount a web app's file system without affecting postgres - if I do that at the moment CHECKPOINTs fail to run, so CREATE DATABASE, VACUUM, and other commands fail.

Is there a way to "deactivate" a database so that PostgreSQL won't try to checkpoint or autovacuum it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with PostgreSQL at this time.

What you're talking about is more like a "quiesce" or "stop" than a "detach". You don't seem to want to be able to move it from one PostgreSQL instance to another.

The issues are:

- Transaction IDs are global. Pg would have to stop all writes to the DB then `VACUUM FREEZE` it, which is quite expensive, to make sure there would be no txid wrap-around issues when it was re-enabled.
- Pg needs to be able to tell if a database contains objects that depend on a global object like a user, so when you `DROP USER` it can reject the attempt if it'd violate dependencies.
- ... and probably more

I don't think it's impossible, theoretically, but it's not going to be trivial to impliment. It also won't be very useful - I don't see what you gain from this over simply leaving the DB unused, or at most forcing a `VACUUM FREEZE`. Checkpoint activity is insignificant to nil if there's no activity in the DB, same with autovacuum.

Comment: Yes a "stop" is what I'm after. The reason I want to unmount the tablespace is because it is encrypted, and unmounting the drive makes the data inaccessible without the passphrase.

Comment: @Jez Huh. OK, that's a good reason. I don't think it'd be particularly technically difficult to implement something like this in PostgreSQL, but it's not supported at the moment.